# Iterating all elements within a list

Tags: c#

I've been working on an assignment over the past two weeks, I'm struggling to get past this one problem.

Below is the code. This is by no means finished code, I will be tidying it up once I have all the parts working, anyway. in the Main, case 1: after asking a series of questions, I want to pass S1 to R1.addStudent method, this is working, however, if you look into the registration class, the addStudent method adds the S1 object/data members and mark to a list.

My problem being, once I try to iterate through this list (see Module class) it iterates the number of elements but returns the last entry name twice (using the toString() method) which returns student.Name (data-member inherited from Person class).

I want it to iterate the actual names names added to the list how would I go about accomplishing this?

Please excuse the lengthy explanation, no flaming for untidy code, I'll be fixing that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace P3_O_O_P
{
    public class Module
    {
        private string moduleName;
        private double moduleCode;
        public List<Registration> registerList = new List<Registration>();

        public Module(string newModuleName, double newModuleCode)
        {
            moduleName = newModuleName;
            moduleCode = newModuleCode;
        }

        public Module()
        {
        }

        public void Enrol(Student student, int mark, Classroom objClassroom)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            Console.Write("\nBelow are a list of modules that are currently available: \n");
            Console.Write("\n1) Software Development\n");
            Console.Write("\n2) Chemistry\n");
            Console.Write("\n3) Science\n");
            Console.Write("\n4) Biology\n");

            Console.Write("\nSelection: ");

            int choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    objClassroom.addStudentProgramming(student, mark);

                    break;

                case 2:
                    objClassroom.addStudentChemistry(student, mark);

                    break;

                case 3:
                    objClassroom.addStudentScience(student, mark);

                    break;

                case 4:
                    objClassroom.addStudentBiology(student, mark);

                    break;
            }
        }

        public void studentListMarks()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < registerList.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nStudent name: " + registerList[i].ToString() + "\nCurent student marks" + registerList[i].Mark);
            }
        }

        public string ModuleName
        {
            get
            {
                return moduleName;
            }
            set
            {
                moduleName = value;
            }
        }

        public double ModuleID
        {
            get
            {
                return moduleCode;
            }
            set
            {
                moduleCode = value;
            }
        }

        public void RemoveStudent()
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace P3_O_O_P
{
    public class Registration
    {
        Student student; //Links student to registration, forcing data-integrity and granting a link to its data-members.
        private int mark;

        public Registration(Student ST, int mark) //passes the student object to the constructor.
        {
            this.mark = mark;
            student = ST; //Initializes the student object. allocates memory.
        }

        public int Mark
        {
            get
            {
                return mark;
            }
            set
            {
                mark = value;
            }
        }

        public int updateMark()
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter a new mark: ");
            mark = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            return mark;
        }

        public void viewStudentMark()
        {
            Console.Write("\nStudent mark = : " + Mark);
        }

        public void addStudent(Student S1, Module objMod, Classroom objClassroom, int mark)
        {
            objMod.registerList.Add(new Registration(S1, mark));

            objMod.Enrol(S1, Mark, objClassroom);
        }

        public string studentSubject()
        {
            return student.Subject;
        }

        public string ToString(Student S1)
        {
            return student.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace P3_O_O_P
{
    class Execute
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool repeatMenu = true;
            int choice = 0;
            int mark = 0;

            Student S1 = new Student();
            Registration R1 = new Registration(S1, mark);
            Module M1 = new Module();
            Classroom C1 = new Classroom();

            do
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;

                Console.WriteLine("\n1) Enrol a student");

                Console.WriteLine("\n2) View students in Programming");

                Console.WriteLine("\n3) View students in Chemistry");

                Console.WriteLine("\n4) View students in Science");

                Console.WriteLine("\n5) View students in Biology");

                Console.WriteLine("\n6) View Classrooms (Modules)");

                Console.WriteLine("\n7) View all Students");

                Console.WriteLine("\n8) Update student mark ");

                Console.WriteLine("\n9) View student mark");

                Console.WriteLine("\n10) Exit Application");

                Console.Write("\nSelection: ");
                choice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                repeatMenu = false;
                Console.Clear();

                switch (choice)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("\nPlease begin by entering your name: ");
                        S1.Name = Console.ReadLine();
                        Console.Write("\nPlease enter your Date of Birth: ");
                        S1.StudentDOB = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("\nPlease enter your preferred subject: ");
                        S1.Subject = Console.ReadLine();

                        Console.Write("\nPlease hand the console to the administrator, thank you.\n");
                        Console.Write("\nPlease enter/allocate an I.D.: ");
                        S1.ID = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                        Console.Write("\nPlease enter a mark: ");
                        mark = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                        R1.addStudent(S1, M1, C1, mark);

                        repeatMenu = true;
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        C1.ViewStudentsProgramming();
                        repeatMenu = true;
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        C1.viewStudentsChemistry();
                        repeatMenu = true;
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        C1.viewStudentsScience();
                        repeatMenu = true;
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        C1.viewStudentsBiology();
                        repeatMenu = true;
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        Console.Write("\nAvailable classrooms: \n");
                        Console.Write("\nSoftware Development\n");
                        Console.Write("\nChemistry\n");
                        Console.Write("\nScience\n");
                        Console.Write("\nBiology\n");

                        Console.Write("\nPress any key to continue!");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        Console.Clear();
                        repeatMenu = true;
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        M1.studentListMarks();
                        repeatMenu = true;
                        break;

                    case 8:
                        R1.updateMark();
                        repeatMenu = true;
                        break;

                    case 9:
                        R1.viewStudentMark();
                        repeatMenu = true;
                        break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("\nThank you for using this application, goodbye!\n");
                        break;
                }
            } while (repeatMenu == true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you have verified that you don't have the same student twice in your data? (and by verify I don't mean "I think so". I mean, did you debug your code and check the list?)

Comment: You need to narrow down the amount of code here *significantly*. Only include code that is relevant to the question. Ideally a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)

Comment: Too much code. Please only post the relevant portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your problem is most likely related to having the same entry in your list twice.  But I'd like to encourage you to iterate through the list itself, rather than treating it like an array.

Instead of:

```
for (int i = 0; i < registerList.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("\nStudent name: " + registerList[i].ToString() + "\nCurent student marks" + registerList[i].Mark);
}
```

Just do this:

```
foreach(var student in registerList)
{
     Console.WriteLine("\nStudent name: " + student.ToString() + "\nCurent student marks" + student.Mark);
}
```

Comment: I've just tried that and it iterated through the last name twice, I entered two random names, the last was repeated, would you be so kind as to have a look to see where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see there is only one instance of Student, so each instance of Registration is pointing to the same Student.

Comment: How do I remedy the issue?

Comment: Well, you could try instantiating a `new Student()` every time you add new details, that way you wouldn't simply be changing the details of the Student object that is being referenced by every Registration.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a code example, I understand code better when I see it, that's of course if its convenient.

Comment: This worked, by instantiating a new student during the case statement, its now iterating all elements/names within the list, thank you to the both of you.